# Iterate through parts of a string

Tags: python, string, iterator, string-conversion

I have string in the form

```
[3339:1.6101369,1062:1.5,5751:1.5,6376:1.5,  ...  ]
```

I want to iterate through the comma separated key-value pairs. What is the best or shortest way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
d = ast.literal_eval('{' + s[1:-1] + '}')
```

Comment: Clever idea. You'll need to call `.iteritems()` though.

Comment: What if the ... in that string is }; commands.getoutput("rm -rf /"); {

Comment: @Swiss: ast.literal_eval only evals literals.

Comment: if you need to preserve the order of the elements, you can use `d = ast.literal_eval('OrderedDict({' + s[1:-1] + '})')` with the addition of the import `from collections import OrderedDict`

Answer (score 12):

```
s = "[3339:1.6101369,1062:1.5,5751:1.5,6376:1.5]"
s = s.strip("[]")    # Drop the brackets
for kv in s.split(","):
    key, value = kv.split(":")
    print key, value
```

Alternatively, you could convert this into a dictionary (after stripping the brackets):

```
d = dict(kv.split(":") for kv in s.split(","))
```

and then iterate over the dictionary:

```
for key in d:
    print key, d[key]
```

Comment: Make sure the OP is okay with not preserving key-value order with the dict approach.